# Converting a vector into formula

Tags: r

Given a data.frame and a vector only with -1,0,1 with length equal to the number of columns of the data.frame. Is there a natural way to transform the vector into a formula with those elements in position with a -1 appear on the left side of the formula and those with +1 appear on the right side?

For example, given the following data.frame

```
df = data.frame(
  'a' = rnorm(10),
  'b' = rnorm(10),
  'c' = rnorm(10),
  'd' = rnorm(10),
  'e' = rnorm(10))
```

and following vector `vec = c(-1,-1,0,1,1)`.

Is there a natural way to build formula `a+b~d+e`?

Answer (score 1):

We assume that if there are no 1's in `vec` that we should use a right hand side of  1 and if there are no -1's in `vec` then the left hand side is empty.

The alternatives each produce a character string but if a formula class object is wanted use `formula(s)` where `s` is that string.

**1) paste each side** Subset out the names corresponding to vec -1 giving LHS and paste/collapse them and do the same with vec 1 giving RHS and paste those with ~ all together.  If we knew that there were at least one 1 in `vec` we could omit the `if` statement. Of the solutions here this seems the most straightforward.

```
nms <- names(df)
LHS <- paste(nms[vec == -1], collapse = "+")
RHS <- paste(nms[vec == 1], collapse = "+")
if (RHS == "") RHS <- "1"
paste0(LHS, "~", RHS)
## [1] "a+b~d+e"
```

**2) sapply** Alternately combine the LHS and RHS lines into a single `sapply`. If we knew that there were at least one 1 in `vec` then we could 
simplify the code by omitting the `if` statement.  This approach is shorter than (1).

```
sa <- sapply(c(-1, 1), function(x) paste(names(df)[vec == x], collapse = "+"))
if (sa[2] == "") sa[2] <- "1"
paste0(sa[1], "~", sa[2])
## [1] "a+b~d+e"
```

**3) tapply**  We can alternately combine the LHS and RHS lines into a single `tapply` like this:

```
ta <- tapply(names(df), vec, paste, collapse = "+")
paste0(if (any(vec == -1)) ta[["-1"]], "~", if (any(vec == 1)) ta[["1"]] else 1)
## [1] "a+b~d+e"
```

If we knew that -1 and 1 each appear at least once in `vec` then we can simplify the last line to:

```
paste0(ta[["-1"]], "~", ta[["1"]]])
## [1] "a+b~d+e"
```

Overall this approach is the shortest if we can guarantee that there will be at least one 1 and at least one -1 but otherwise handling the edge cases seems somewhat cumbersome compared to the other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

We could do this by creating a group by `paste`

```
paste(aggregate(nm ~ vec, subset(data.frame(nm = names(df), vec, 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE), vec != 0),
    FUN = paste, collapse= ' + ')[['nm']], collapse=' ~ ')
#[1] "a + b ~ d + e"
```

---

Or another option is `tapply`

```
paste(tapply(names(df), vec, FUN = paste, 
        collapse= ' + ')[c('-1', '1')], collapse= ' ~ ')
#[1] "a + b ~ d + e"
```